# How do I "disable" constraints without removing them?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, autolayout

I have a app which works on portrait mode and landscape mode. When I turn around my device, some of my labels and buttons are not shown, so I would like to have them on the side.

There is a way to remove constraints

```
[self.view removeConstraint:myConstraint];
```

This method removes the constraint, so when I turn the device back to portrait mode, I have to create the constraints again with code which is really frustrating.

Is there any way to just disable constraint without actually removing them?

Comment: Have you considered using constraints that actually works for both portrait and landscape? You can use size classes for it in iOS8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This method removes the constraint, so when I turn the device back to portrait mode, I have to create the constraints again with code which is really frustrating.

Stop and ask yourself why it's "really frustrating". It shouldn't be! If it is, you're doing it wrong.

Removing constraints and replacing them with other constraints is standard procedure, and is really easy. Swapping constraints in and out of the interface is how you move things around, especially as a way of changing the interface in response to rotation. It's just a question of getting all your ducks in a row. Put one set of constraints in one array; put another set of constraints in another array; and when it's time to swap, remove one set and add the other! Simple as can be.

Here's some actual code (it's Swift, but that won't hurt any):

```
func doSwap(landscape:Bool) {
    if landscape {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints(self.constraintsWith)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(self.constraintsWithout)
    } else {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints(self.constraintsWithout)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(self.constraintsWith)
    }
}
```

Note the use of the new-in-iOS-8 `NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints` and `NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints`. This is a real work-saver because you don't need to attach the constraints to any particular view; it's done for you, automatically.

Comment: Matt, have you found that the new activateConstraints and deactivateConstraints work correctly? I tried using them to answer another question, and I couldn't get them to work. For instance, I could activate a set of constraints (from an outlet collection) without deactivating the initial ones, and I got no errors, even though they were conflicting constraints (the view showed up where it should for the newly activated constraints). When I rotated to landscape and back, the view went back to the original constraints. A log of self.view.constraints shows them all.

Comment: Correction to may last comment. Actually, with both sets of constrains active (after calling activateConstraints on the uninstalled group), the view was placed in what looked like some mash up of the two sets. If I deactivate the original set, and activate the new ones, the view is where it's supposed to be, but still reverts to the initially installed ones after rotation.

Comment: @rdelmar Well, the example project I got that code from works; here it is if you want to try it out (and of course if there _is_ a problem with these commands, I really to want to know about it!): https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/b8afd9e2d50a7877f866a699abbf3d0cd7d20d85/bk2ch01p032constraintSwapping2

Answer (score 3):

If you have the constraint as an iVar you can remove it from the view, maintain a strong reference to it and then add it back when you want to.

It saves having to create it again.

Answer (score -4):

To Disable all table constraints

```
ALTER TABLE TableName NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ConstraintName
```

-- Enable all table constraints

```
ALTER TABLE TableName CHECK CONSTRAINT ConstraintName
```